# Помощь с полями

Tags: c#

Мне нужно сделать так чтоб я смог получить значение Name класса Worker через класс Team без static полей, есть такая  возможность?

```
{
    interface IWorker
    {
        public string Name { get; }
    }
    public class Team
    {
        public Team(List<Worker> w)
        {
            WS = w;
        }
        public Team(List<Worker> w, TeamLeader tl)
        {
            WS = w;
            TL = tl;
        }

        public TeamLeader TL { get; set; }
        public List<Worker> WS { get; set; }
        public List<string> report = new List<string>();
    }
    public class Worker : IWorker
    {
        public Worker(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        string IWorker.Name => Name;
    }
    public class TeamLeader : IWorker
    {
        public TeamLeader(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }

        public static string Name { get; set; }
        string IWorker.Name => Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: В `Team` у вас список `Worker`-ов, от какого из них вы хотите `Name` получить? А вообще я сегодня видел уже тут этот вопрос. Задание что ли на каких-то курсах дали?

Comment: @CrazyElf 1. Да хотелось бы так. 2. Да задание с курсов. Можете помочь?

Comment: Ещё раз. В `Team` у вас **список** объектов `Worker`. Поле `Name` можно получить у **одного** объекта `Worker`. Что именно вы хотите получить от **списка** объектов `Worker`?

Comment: @CrazyElf Мне нужно получить Name от WS очередно, а еще лучше если через новое поле в Team я смогу получать Name Worker.

Comment: `team.WS[0].Name`

Comment: @bigidulka Ещё раз. Вот есть целый класс школьников: Петя, Вася, Иван, Степан, и ещё 20 человек. Имя какого из них вы хотите узнать? Вы говорите: хочу узнать имя у целого класса школьников, вот же у одного школьника есть имя, хочу также точно узнать имя у целого класса. Я вам объясняю - в классе толпа школьников, у какого из них вы хотите узнать имя? И так по кругу.

Comment: Возможность то взять имя есть - берите любой объект из списка `WS`, у него будет `.Name`, всё легко. Непонятно только одно - у какого их объектов этого списка нужно взять имя.

Comment: @CrazyElf У меня задача сделать чтобы имена шли поочередно друг за другом когда я получаю их имена.

Comment: @CrazyElf public string GetNameWorker 
        {
            get { return WS[0].Name; } 
        } // Так я буду получать только 1 имя рабочего

Comment: Уже лучше. Тут возможны варианты. Либо вернуть выборку `.Name` у всех элементов списка с помощью `LINQ` (через `.Select`), либо сделать цикл `foreach` и делать `yield` `.Name` каждого перебираемого элемента.

Comment: @CrazyElf А про цикл можно поподробней, я синтаксис не понимаю как оформить

Comment: foreach(var worker in WS) и делаете что нужно с worker.Name

Answer (score 1):

Вы уже можете это сделать, т.к. определили в классе Team лист из Worker. Поэтому чтобы вытащить имена игроков вы просто пропускаете его через foreach и обращаетесь к свойству Name:

```
foreach(var worker in Team.WS)
{
    Console.WriteLine(worker.Name);
}
```

И если вы не против я пожалуй скажу, что можно для капитана команды можно использовать тот же класс Worker, только добавить к класс булево поле IsCaptain, которое помечается true или false в зависимости от того, капитан о или нет.

Comment: Дополнительное поле в принципе и не нужно - можно проверять `person is TeamLeader`, это ничем не хуже проверки `person.IsCaptain`, только во втором случае лишнее поле вводится.

Comment: С помощью is идет динамическая проверка соответствия типа person и TeamLeader, это более ресурсоемко, чем проверить булево поле. Да и потом, это выглядит лаконичнее, нежели вводить новый класс TeamLeader, который по сути является таким же игроком (Worker)

Comment: Ну вообще по принципам `SOLID` всё же лучше реализовывать такие вещи с помощью наследования. И тут скорее всего `TeamLeader` будет иметь ещё какую-то функциональность, не только одним полем отличаться. Но даже если и будет точно таким же, всё-равно по принципам ООП лучше, чтобы разные сущности были разными классами, а не одним классом с кучей свойств, по которым их можно между собой различать.

Comment: На данный момент по коду можно определить, что содержимое классов Worker и TeamLeader одинаковое. Исходя из этого было бы лучшим решением сделать вышеописанное мной